# How to avoid the spell check on string in Pycharm

Tags: python, syntax, pycharm

Where is the option to disable the spell check on the strings for the PyCharm IDE?
I hate the jagged line under my comments and strings.

Comment: @Close Voters: I see 2 of you suggest moving this to SU. Questions about programming tools are [on-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so I disagree with these particular close votes.

Comment: In case if this is not the spell checker -- please show a screenshot with some example code.

Answer (score 134):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`. Expand the list under `Spelling` in the middle window and uncheck the option `Typo`.

[image]

However, practically most of the jagged line is caused by violations of the [PEP 8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). If you would like to disable this option too, in the same window, expand the list under `Python` and uncheck the option `PEP 8 coding style violation`.

Comment: `# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection`

Comment: Thanks @MarkRibau. How to do it for a specific **comment**? There doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: I just put that on the line above the line with the false spelling error. Does that help you?

Comment: For me there was no 'Spelling' section, it was under 'Proofreading'

Comment: @KellyBang Thanks, that seemed to be the case for me too. Maybe in the newer versions they changed the location.

Answer (score 19):

In the latest version of PyCharm it appears as ProofReading:

[image: ProofReading]

Answer (score 11):

You can disable spellchecking for specific code section by commenting `# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection` above it.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/spellchecking.html

Comment: For some strange reason I have to insert the directive two lines in a row for it to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

PyCharm does **not** check the *syntax* inside strings and comments. It checks *spelling*.

You can find the settings of the spell-checker under the *Settings...* page. There is a *Spelling* page inside *Project Settings*. Inside this page, at the bottom of the *Dictionaries* tab you can enable/disable dictionaries. If you don't want spell checking simply disable all of them.

Note that it is possible to add custom words in the spell checker, or, if you already have a dictionary on your computer, you can add it. This can turn out useful if you want to spell check different languages (for example Italian).

In particular if you are using a Linux system and you have installed the Italian language pack, you probably have the Italian dictionary under: `/usr/share/dict/italian`.
You can add the `/usr/share/dict` directory to the directories searched for dictionaries and enable the `italian` dictionary.

---

It seems like PyCharm only checks files with the `.dic` extension. If you want to use `/usr/share/dict/italian` you should probably either copy it into an other directory renaming it `italian.dic` or you could create a symbolic link.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the best option is to disable typo checks **only for code**. This way green lines under variable/method/class names and strings disappear, but PyCharm still controls comments to avoid misspellings, so You have both nice compact code and fully understandable docs.

I don't exactly know since which PyCharm version this option is accessible, but for sure in revision 2020.2 if You highlight a **Typo** in **Settings > Editor > Inspections > Proofreading** there are three additional options in the right panel - just uncheck Process code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For single line you can use the `# noqa` at the end of the line and it will suppress spelling inspections (the squiggly green line).

`GOOFY_API_USERNAME_THING = "LAksdfallae@#lkdaslekserlse#lsese"  # noqa`

I'm using PyCharm 2021.3.2

Answer (score 2):

In the newer version of PyCharm, go to Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> Spelling.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add particular typo word to PyCharm dictionary by pressing Alt + Enter this word and select `Save [typo word] to dictionary`. Sometimes this is best choice for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to disable typos only in string literals in [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/spellchecking.html#configure-the-typo-inspection) by disabling **process literals**, but it doesn't work for me (maybe it's a bug, that will be fixed in the future).

[Settings->Proofreading->Typo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG4WN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here.

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Spelling`
or

press Double `Shift` and search `'Spelling'`